# Почему в одном случае привязка работает, а во втором нет?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <MenuItem Header="Click Me" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Click Me" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </Menu>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string MyText { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(MyText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Замечательный вопрос!**

Дело в том, что при создании интерфейса когда мы используем **`Menu`**, то само меню не перехватывает фокус текущего элемента при нажатии на дочерний **`MenuItem`**. Так как в режиме привязки к **`TextBox`** по умолчанию стоит режим обновления свойства **`LostFocus`**, то соответственно обновиться свойство не может, так как фокус остается на **`TextBox`**e. Это сделано для того, чтобы валидация проходила только после потери фокуса, а не после каждого изменения значения **`TextBox`** при наборе.

В первом примере нет меню как такового, а **`MenuItem`** считается простым контролом. Поэтому при нажатии на него **`TextBox`** теряет фокус и свойство обновляется.

Проблемы или ошибки здесь нет. Для решения данной задачи нужно просто выбрать другой режим обновления для **`TextBox`**а.

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```